# Good way in iOS to have a view outside a UITabViewController

Tags: ios, ads

I'm just getting back into iOS development after a year or so away and am looking for a way to  have a single view above or below a UITabViewController view. The idea is to have one ad view that is used throughout the app instead of one on each tab. The constant reinitializing of the ad view seems like it would be a lot of overhead so having one persist throughout would seem to be more effective.

I've searched for this but not found much of anything so even a useful link would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several approaches here:

1. Since you are setting up your view hierarchy in your application's delegate, I'd suggest creating a separate `UIViewController` and managing it from your app delegate. That way you can show/hide it in the main UIWindow, without having to do much work.
2. You can subclass `UITabBarController` and show the ad in the visible view controller. This is more work, but your app architecture is arguably cleaner, because your app delegate doesn't get cluttered with ad-related code.
3. Another option is to look into a `UIViewController` category, where you can manage add related code. Not necessarily the cleanest, but it keeps the ads out of both your app delegate, and your tab bar controller. (You'd add the ad view as a category property via runtime level calls and associate objects, but that gets messy.)

I'd probably go with the first approach if it were me, but I could argue for either of the other two approaches, since an ad view doesn't really necessitate it's own view controller.

Comment: I think you're right in that 1 seems to most natural. Would be useful for other kinds of view controllers as well, not just ads. Now I just need to figure out how to manage the layout of the views. I can't believe how much I've forgotten in the last year.

Answer (score 1):

How about create a parent view controller and each view controller inherits from that parent view controller? Parent view controller has a ad view or table view, so every child view controller will has those two view as well.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I think I'm leaning towards keeping the ad structure separated out into it's own ViewController though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after spending some time trying to create and manage a customer view controller for this I stumbled on the Container View Controller capability Apple added in iOS 5. I have no need to support iOS 4 or earlier so this works good for me. There's a good description of it here (unfortunately the author never wrote part 2 with a tutorial):

[Container View Controller description](http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/post/12383262201/container-view-controllers-part-i-one-of-the)

And a decent tutorial is available here:

[Container View Controller tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/)

Between the two of these I was able to create a good setup with an AdViewController and BodyViewController (TabBarController) contained in a Container View Controller. This gives me all the capabilities I need (at least so far).